# How to properly structure a mysql table with similar data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm having trouble coming up with a good way to define my subscriptions system. I want users to be able to subscribe to other users, posts, and tags. My initial thought was to have a subscriptions table with the following schema

```
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id int NOT NULL
subscription_id int NOT NULL
subscription_type int NOT NULL
subscribe_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
unsubscribe_date timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
notification_frequency int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1440 //number of minutes in  day
```

The subscription_type would be `0` for `users`, and `1` for `posts` and `2` for `tags` and the `subscription_id` would be the id of the row of that element, sometimes a user_id, sometimes a post_id, sometimes a tag_id.

There has got to be a better way, and the only other ways I can think of seem worse. Like making multiple subscription tables, one for each `subscription_type`. Or Implementing `uuid` fields across all users/posts/tags in my system.

There has got to be a way I can indicate there are multiple subscription types, without needing this extra column with arbitrary integer values for each type of subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

- 3 tables, or
- 3 `SELECTs` in a `UNION`, with or without uuids, or
- 3 `CASE` elements, each with a subquery
- ...

And...

- Long, messy SQL, or
- Long, messy application code, or
- Some of each.